# How to solve KeyError for iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I currently have a dataframe which include a column called `timeAccepted`.

I'm trying to print the value of `timeAccepted` for every iteration. I'm simply using the following code:

```
def print_time(df):
    print(df['timeAccepted'])
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        print(df.columns)
        print(df.at[i, 'timeAccepted'])
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
KeyError: 'timeAccepted'
```

please note that `print(df['timeAccepted'])` have as an output:

```
0        2023-07-27T06:50:03.747135Z
1        2023-07-27T06:50:06.030559Z
2        2023-07-27T06:50:08.025268Z
3        2023-07-27T06:50:10.024531Z
4        2023-07-27T06:50:12.028957Z
                    ...             
26232    2023-07-27T12:46:27.024663Z
26233    2023-07-27T12:46:27.024663Z
26234    2023-07-27T12:45:02.027558Z
26235    2023-07-27T12:46:29.023594Z
26236    2023-07-27T12:46:29.023594Z
Name: timeAccepted, Length: 26237, dtype: object
```

and `print(df.columns)`:

```
Index(['Order identification code', 'Initial quantity', 'side', 'Order type',
       'timeInForce', 'Limit price', 'quoteId', 'userId', 'timeAccepted'], dtype='object')
```

So, I've checked and the column do exist in the dataframe but I'm still having the KeyError! Please help!

Comment: Unable to repro, but why not use `print(row['timeAccepted'])`?

Comment: Please [edit] your post with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/1422451) including sample data and full code from `import` lines to code that calls defined method. Test your reprex in an _empty_ Python environment preferably outside an IDE like the `python.exe` command line compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Try to inspect the Index names a bit deeper:

```
index_names = df.columns.to_list()
time_accepted_index = index_names[-1]
print(len(time_accepted_index))
if not time_accepted_index == 'timeAccepted':
    print('strings are not the same')
```

I got a similar case where the index name had trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I've tried it and the strings are identical. Perhaps, the ```row['timeAccepted']``` solved the issue!